# Create a new colum only with non-NA in specific columns [R]

Tags: r, apply, na

I've got the following data structure...

```
> data <- data.frame(txt = paste0("f", 1:8), 
    a = c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "A", NA, "C"), 
    b = c("D", "A", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    c = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", NA))

> data
#   txt    a    b    c
# 1  f1 <NA>    D <NA>
# 2  f2 <NA>    A <NA>
# 3  f3 <NA>    C <NA>
# 4  f4    A <NA> <NA>
# 5  f5    B <NA> <NA>
# 6  f6    A <NA> <NA>
# 7  f7 <NA> <NA>    C
# 8  f8    C <NA> <NA>
```

... and I want to create a new column containing the value of these non-NA columns (theoretically, only one col).

```
> data$tmp <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) gsub("NA", "", paste(as.data.frame(data[i,-1]), collapse = "")))
> data
#   txt    a    b    c tmp
# 1  f1 <NA>    D <NA>   D
# 2  f2 <NA>    A <NA>   A
# 3  f3 <NA>    C <NA>   C
# 4  f4    A <NA> <NA>   A
# 5  f5    B <NA> <NA>   B
# 6  f6    A <NA> <NA>   A
# 7  f7 <NA> <NA>    C   C
# 8  f8    C <NA> <NA>   C
```

This code seems to work as I want, but I have millions of rows and it's soooo slow... any could help me to find a better solution, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(tmp = coalesce(a,b,c))
     a    b    c tmp
1 <NA>    D <NA>   D
2 <NA>    A <NA>   A
3 <NA>    C <NA>   C
4    A <NA> <NA>   A
5    B <NA> <NA>   B
6    A <NA> <NA>   A
7 <NA> <NA>    C   C
8    C <NA> <NA>   C
```

Comment: A nice (and simple) response, thanks... and any way to consider these columns without writing them?? (because I usually do a `grep` to find my cols).

Comment: @jgarces, see if this works: data %>% mutate(tmp = do.call(coalesce, data))

Comment: Perfectly, I works nicely! I had to adjust to my data but `do.call(coalesce, data)` did it what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

In case its only one column to select maybe using matrix subset is faster:

```
data$tmp <- data[matrix(c(seq_len(nrow(data)),
   apply(!is.na(data), 1, which.max)), ncol=2)]
```

Or using the approach from @Ventrilocus

```
tt <- t(data)
data$tmp <- tt[!is.na(tt)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, I re-edited my question because I've also a text column I don't want to consider. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The following works if there is only one non-NA value per row:

```
data$tmp = data[!is.na(data)]
```

Comment: Yes, very simple and useful, thanks a lot. I forget to mention that I've also a text column that I don't want to consider and it's crashing all your responses...

Comment: try: data$tmp = data[!is.na(data[, -i])] # Where i is the index of the column you want to ignore.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I get this error: `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, tmp, value = c("f4", "f5", "f6", "f8",  : replacement has 12 rows, data has 8`... with `data$tmp = data[!is.na(data[,-1])] `

Answer (score 1):

We can use `row/column` indexing with `max.col`

```
data$tmp <- data[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), max.col(!is.na(data[-1]), 'first'))]
data$tmp
#[1] "D" "A" "C" "A" "B" "A" "C" "C"
```